# how to discover a class's instance level fields given a class name

Tags: python, member, inspect

Given the following class **Mock**, I want to write a function **get_members** that returns a and b when the input is the class Mock. This task is easy if you are allowed to use an object of Mock as the input of this function to be written ( you can use "_ *dict*_" or vars or inspect etc), but looks impossible if Mock (the class Mock itself rather than an object of Mock) is used as the input as neither vars, dir or inspect has knowledge on the existence of field a.

```
class Mock:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a

    def b():
        pass

def get_members(clz):
    """return all the members of clz and its instance, including static methods, 
       class methods, instance level methods and fields
       e.g., given Mock, return a and b
    """
```

Comment: There is no way to know from the class itself, because attributes don't have to be added inside a class definition. For example, `class Foo: pass`, then, `foo = Foo(); foo.bar = 42`

Comment: Now, you could write code that introspects the source code and make a guess. But what exactly is your use case?

Comment: I don't understand, Could you post an example? In your code you haven't defined such function (I assume you mean a method?). Please define the (method?) and put comments on what it should do. You want a method that receives a parameter, and determines if this parameter is an instance of the class Mock?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga make sense. I guess to I have to ask the user to pass in an object in this case to know the object level variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my use case is to write some code to auto generate some code to be exposed as EXCEL functions based on the classes that is supplied by the users. Of course, the users would want to call the instance level fields, but it would look a bit cumbersome that you have to ask them to supply an instance (which may or may not be expensive to create) instead of a class

Comment: The problem is that the `Mock` class doesn't have an attribute `a`.  Only instances of `Mock` get an attribute `a`.  Compare `dir(Mock)` with `dir(Mock(1))`.

Comment: Ok, then you should just make explicitly adding the fields as a part of the class definition. Most straightforward solution

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you mean explicitly supply the fields of a class to be exposed (a in the example above ) ? Then it defeats the purpose of auto generation, and if a is renamed to c, you have to explicitly change it.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know if I understood what you want

But you can have a method in your class Mock with a special unusual name (eg: `someRandomMethodName122345`)

When you get a param, try to call this method from the param, if the call returns True it means that the parameter has a method called `someRandomMethodName122345`, so it's probably a Mock (more probable if you call the method a random name unlikely to be present in any other class.

If you get an exception, the parameter is not a Mock instance

```
class Mock:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @staticmethod
    def someRandomMethodName122345():
        return True

    def checkMockInstance(self, param):
        # checks if param is a Mock instance
        try:
            if param.someRandomMethodName122345():
                # param most likely is a mock instance, return self.a
                return self.a
        except AttributeError:
            # param is surely not a Mock instance, return false?
            return False
```

You haven;t defined what needs to be done if param is not a mock instance, in this example I return False, but this makes the return type inconsistent: sometimes False is returned, sometimes a is returned (whatever a is)

Comment: Huh? The problem isn't identifying mock instances, or the class Mock itself, both of which can be checked directly